# How to Control Scrolling on a Website Through Links and Dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How would you be able to control on a scroll intensive website where the user is by (1) clicking on a link and (2) dragging an image. Essentially, how would I do what [this site did](http://www.sixspokemedia.com/) with the map on the bottom right and with links on the navigation bar.

Comment: `window.scrollTo()` all the things!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you would have to use JavaScript's `scrollLeft()` and `scrollTop()` methods on link click to take them to certain areas of the page. Be careful about this though. It can be quite slow on some devices if you have a lot of content.

For dragging certain objects on the page (or for dragging the entire page itself), you'll want to use a library like [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/). You can bind a drag event to a certain element or to the page itself and then use `scrollLeft()` and `scrollTop()` to control the page.

To "show" movement as you scroll, use jQuery's `animate()` function.

```
$(window).animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 5000);
```

Comment: Would this work with dragging an image as well? For scrolling down and right, would you just input negative values?

Comment: Is there a way to show the movement from one point to another rather than just jumping from point a to point b? Other than that, it seems like it will work.

Comment: See the new additions to my answer.